# Measuring the colloidal nanoparticles stability by dynamic light scattering

Tags: stability, nanotechnology

In this [article](http://pubs.rsc.org/en/Content/ArticleLanding/2014/RA/c4ra05035e#!divAbstract) the ligand exchange reaction is done for thiol coating of gold nanoparticles.In the first step dicholoromethane (DCM) is used as a extraction solvent to remove CTAC(Cetyl trimethylammonium chloride) from the gold nanoparticle's surface.CTAC acts as a stabilizer for gold nanoparticles.However,only incomplete CTAC removal occurs to ensure that there is still enough CTAC present to maintain colloidal stability.The optimum of solvent extraction is determined by dynamic light scattering.
My question is "How can be measured the the optimum solvent extraction by dynamic light scattering?"

Comment: This question is very broad and probably covered by a couple of textbooks of the field. In its current state it asks too much to be a fit for our format and to attract a high quality answer. If you can narrow the scope, for example to a specific problem you face, please [edit] the question. Otherwise I assume this questions might get closed and stays without an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic light scattering is a sizing technique; that is, it provides an indirect measurement of the size of nanoparticles (details may vary depending on experimental set-up).

However, it's important to note that it doesn't provide a direct measurement of the solid particle, but of its *effective size when moving in solution*. In other words, it measures the [hydrodynamic radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrodynamic_radius) of the nanoparticles - which, by the way, is not a single value but an ensemble average, which you usually measure in statistical fashion.

Now, at the nanoparticle-solution interface, you have several layers of material that is bounded to the surface and will move around with the nanoparticle, contributing to the hydrodynamic radius. In this particular paper, you have a CTAB/C monolayer (at least) which will be more or less tightly bounded to the gold particle, and also counter-ions to provide charge balance and several shells of solvation water (progressively less ordered and more weakly bound as you move away from the particle). It's the size of that whole entity that you measure (indirectly) with DLS.

As you can imagine, reducing the concentration of CTAB/C in the solution will change nanoparticle coverage - and will change the size, shape and strength of the layers surrounding the nanoparticle. As with colloidal systems, when synthesising nanoparticles there's a real concern that they can aggregate and precipitate or otherwise change their properties - which is the reason that you produce them in the presence of an stabiliser such as CTAB/C in the first place. If you look at figure 4, the histograms show hydrodynamic size for DLS measurements in different conditions and you can see they show that this aggregation isn't happening: if it did, you'd see far larger objects moving around in the solution. And as the body of the article explains, the small changes in hydrodynamic radius are probably due to the removal of CTAB/C from the nanoparticle surface, which affects solvation shells and changes the DLS-measured radius.